# How to easily modify the UID of a Mifare Classic Card?

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, uid

I want to modify the UID of a Mifare Classic Mini 13.56MhZ card, in order to duplicate the one I use to access my dormroom. I believe the security of the door is only based on the UID.
I made a lot of research on the web but couldn't find a precise answer. I know there are specific cards whose UID can be changed, but I still don't know how.

I first thought I could do it with my phone but it doesn't seem to work.
I came across several devices, such as Chameleon Tiny (which allows to store several cards on a single device if I understood well) or Proxmark 3.

In case the security is not UID based, I watched a video saying the Mifare cards could be easily bruteforced, but I don't know if that applies to every Mifare card and how it could be done. If the encryption of the card is bruteforced, are you able to fully duplicate it ?

I just want to know what is the right device to achieve my goal, and also the cheapest.

Then I would like to know how easy it is once we have the right devices.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Authentic MIFARE cards UID can't be changed it is protected by NXP, however there are counterfeit MIFARE cards available in the market where you can change the UID of the card. It is not advisable to use counterfeit cards and also one shouldn't just rely on the UID of the card for identification.

You can use NXP Tag Info application on android phone to check whether your card is an authentic product by NXP.